# telethon forwarding messages to group

Tags: python, telethon

I'm creating a script to forward messages it worked perfectly, but I created a graphical interface and put the id group data in tkinter entries, and then the code stopped working I also put the ids in inputs and it doesn't work,
the code runs but does not forward the msg would anyone know how to solve it

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
import asyncio

with open('Id1.txt', 'r')as f:
    Id_Group1 = f.read()

with open('Id2.txt', 'r')as j:
    Id_Group2 = j.read()

print (Id_Group1, Id_Group2)
api_id = '#######'
api_hash = '#######################'
client = TelegramClient('none', api_id, api_hash)
@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def handler(event):
    chat = await event.get_chat()
    chat_id = event.chat_id
    print('{} {}'.format(chat_id, chat))

    if chat_id == Id_Group1: 
        await client.send_message(Id_Group2, event.raw_text)
client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because your code in if condition will never execute.

The problem is

chat_id is and Integer and
Id_Group1 is a String.

according to python and almost all other programming language.

"-1001659707082" is not equal to -1001659707082

Here is the modified codes..

```
    import asyncio
    from telethon import TelegramClient
    from telethon.sync import events
        

Id_Group1 = "-1001659707082"#You can add username and add entity thing instead
Id_Group2 = "thisistest_2"

api_id = 123

api_hash = "12gh3"

print (Id_Group1, Id_Group2)

client = TelegramClient('none', api_id, api_hash)
@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def handler(event):
    chat = await event.get_chat()
    chat_id = event.chat_id

    if str(chat_id) == Id_Group1: 
        print('{} {}'.format(chat_id, chat))
        await client.send_message(Id_Group2, event.text)
client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Also watch the Id_Group1 and Id_Group2

Comment: i hope it helped.. I cannot help like this for no one ... I have been banned idk why..

Comment: Look into [Why are answers no longer being accepted from my account?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans).

Comment: @Timus Bro how can i be free? like i understood and i will mever repeat.. How can i make my id unban?

Comment: See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/14311263). (The way back is hard.)